# Updating your question with the answer

Tags: discussion

If you discover the answer to your question, you shouldn’t be updating the actual question with the answer, right?

Asking in regards to [Module tag pair not working](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/module-tag-pair-not-working/3721)

What’s the protocol here? Edit the question, removing the “UPDATE” portion, and adding a comment that they should post their answer as an actual answer? Or just comment, and let them do the work themselves, so they don’t have to re-type it?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that question did turn into a bit of a mess. As we get more and more experienced users hopefully this should become less of an issue.

Feel free to either post a comment asking them to clean up the question (like I did), or just edit it yourself. You can also edit the question yourself, and copy the answer part into a new answer. In the case of new users though, it's probably better to comment so that we can help them learn to use the system effectively.

Remember that Stack Exchange is part forum, part wiki. The goal is to build a high quality database of questions and answers (not to help people directly, but they are helped as part of the process). So anything which will improve the quality of our Q&A database is generally acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Best to flag for the moderators to deal with or post a comment letting the person know they should post their solution as an answer and accept their answer as correct.

Looks like this person did add their solution as an answer.